# Why does calling setClass on an element not cause the element to be redrawn?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following markup for an anchor element, then I set its `class` with this code:

```js
function checkTechSubmissionDownload() {
    if ($("#ErrorMessage").val()) {
        $("#FinalizeTender .validation-summary-errors").removeClass("hidden");
        $("#techSubDownloadLink").addClass("disabled");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <a id="downloadTechSubLink" href="@Url.Action("TenderPricingTemplateDownload", new { projectId = Model.ProjectId, isClosingDateMissing = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model.ErrorMessage) })" class="btn btn-default" onclick="checkTechSubmissionDownload(); return false;">Generate Technical Submission Spreadsheet</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Where `$("#ErrorMessage").val()` evaluates to truthy so the other code does execute. My problem is that, while my code does make add the `disabled` class to the element, but it initially appears as if without the class. The element in question, `$("#downloadTechSubLink")` appears as if without the `disabled` class  until I click it or somewhere in its parent div.

[image]

The top-most element in the above image is not an input, but my anchor (styled as `disabled`) that is "invisible".

I have tried setting a timeout and calling `$("#downloadTechSubLink").parent().click()` with no effect, only when I manually click the parent or the anchor, does it reappear.

It seems that adding a class to the element doesn't cause the DOM to redraw or something. I have even tried calling `redraw()` on the element after adding the `disabled` class, with no effect.

Comment: Firstly, setting `disabled` on an element does not alone make it invisible - as you can see in the snippet I added to your question. It's possible it's your CSS doing that, though. Secondly, `a` elements cannot have the `disabled` attribute so the issue is moot

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know setting `disabled` on an element does not alone make it invisible but when I try and set it on the `a` element it makes that element invisible. Seeing as I now know an `a` can't have `disabled` (thanks) I will try on a parent element.

Comment: Ok, but be aware that `disabled` only applies to form controls, ie. `input`, `select`, `button` etc

Comment: @ProfK, as Rory mentioned, it's likely that your CSS has a rule like `[disabled] { display: none; }` (or similar) and it causes disabled elements to disappear

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek They only disappear until I click them or their parent, then they become visible, and I have no `click` handlers busy, so it can't be a static css rule.

Comment: Thanks, people who have commented. I have revised the question, as I have revised my code to no longer try and add a `disabled` attribute to an `a` tag.